# What's wrong with the following INSERT IGNORE MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql

The following `CREATE TABLE` statement is valid, and it's working fine:

```
  CREATE TABLE table1 (
                      'ID' int NOT NULL,
                      'PID' varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                      'A' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                      'B' varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                      'C' varchar(100),
                      'D' varchar(100),
                      'E' varchar(100)
                      );
```

However, for the following `INSERT IGNORE` statement I get an invalid MySQL syntax error:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 ('ID', 'PID', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E') 
VALUES (150, 'ABC123', 'ABC', 'ADE', 'ABC', 'ACE', '12345');
```

I also tried:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (ID, PID, A, B, C, D, E) 
VALUES (150, 'ABC123', 'ABC', 'ADE', 'ABC', 'ACE', '12345');
```

Comment: What's the exact error you get?

Comment: The second one should work anyway, but only if the table is indeed created *and* you have rights to modify it *and* the key 'ABC123' doesn't already exist in the table.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I'm currently testing in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) and I'm getting this error: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ID' int NOT NULL, 'PID' varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,`

Comment: The first one, with quotes, is probably wrong. You don't normally quote table columns using these quotes. That also means that your `create table` statement is wrong and the table probably isn't created at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be using backticks instead of single quotes for your column names:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
`ID` int NOT NULL,
`PID` varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
`A` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`B` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
`C` varchar(100),
`D` varchar(100),
`E` varchar(100)
);

INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (`ID`, `PID`, `A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`) 
VALUES (150, 'ABC123', 'ABC', 'ADE', 'ABC', 'ACE', '12345');
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e0b0/1)

Comment: I see. Should've noticed that in the your last answer. Is that the syntax I should always write MySQL `CREATE TABLE` statements in? because I need to use it in Python.

Comment: @tempy - Not familiar with Python. Generally you only have to use backticks if the column name conflicts with a reserved keyword or has special characters. In this particular scenario you can leave out the backticks.

Answer (score 1):

try this . your problem is that you used single quotes around columns in create table instead you should use backticks :

```
   CREATE TABLE table1 (
                  `ID` int NOT NULL,
                  `PID` varchar(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
                  `A` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                  `B` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
                  `C` varchar(100),
                  `D` varchar(100),
                  `E` varchar(100)
                  );

  INSERT IGNORE INTO table1 (ID, PID, A, B, C, D, E) 
 VALUES (150, 'ABC123', 'ABC', 'ADE', 'ABC', 'ACE', '12345');
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c177bc/1)